# RQT ROS2 Galactic not plotting or autoscrolling

Tags: ros2, rqt, rqt-plot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I am getting this weird bug in RQT. I am trying to plot values from two different topics that RQT subscribes to, but the plot stands still. Whatever I do, I am not getting any values plotted, and the plot itself is not moving even though I have autoscroll on. I had the same error using ROS2 Foxy. I did a complete uninstall of ROS2 Foxy and installed ROS2 Galactic, but the problem persists.

In the terminal window where I launch RQT, I get this error message:

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "/opt/ros/galactic/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rqt_topic/topic_widget.py", line 453, in __lt__ return self.data(column, Qt.UserRole) < other_item.data(column, Qt.UserRole) TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'`

Has anyone else encountered this error as well?

ROS_VERSION=2

ROS_PYTHON_VERSION=3

ROS_LOCALHOST_ONLY=0

ROS_DISTRO=galactic

Ubuntu 20.04.3
Linux 5.14.0-1031-oem x86_64

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/398605/rqt-ros2-galactic-not-plotting-or-autoscrolling./) by [MasHyke](https://answers.ros.org/users/90158/mashyke/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2022-04-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ijnek](https://answers.ros.org/users/73298/ijnek/) on 2022-04-06**:
Could you try running `rqt --clear-config`, and reopening the widget? RQt stores configurations between sessions, and this command clears out those configurations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Running `rqt --clear-config` solved the issue!

---

Originally posted by [MasHyke](https://answers.ros.org/users/90158/mashyke/) with karma: 23 on 2022-04-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0